# Pika has no attribute log

Tags: python, tornado, pika

I'm trying to run some python code that uses pika and tornado. I installed both, but get the error

```
File "tornado_conn.py", line 90, in <module>
   pika.log.setup(color=True)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'log'
```

Both packages are installed in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`

This is my first time playing with python, so I really don't know why it can't find it. Everything seems right in the code:

```
# Helper class PikaClient
application.pika = PikaClient()

# Set our pika.log options
pika.log.setup(color=True)
# Start the HTTP Server
pika.log.info("Starting Tornado HTTPServer on port %i" % PORT)
http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
http_server.listen(PORT)
```

Comment: What version of pika are you using?

Comment: @daharon it's pika 0.9.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [latest Pika release](https://github.com/pika/pika/tree/0.9.12/pika), it looks like [they removed the log module](https://github.com/pika/pika/commit/b84d2bc0023790beca407ee30fe01df42c98d8d7) some time ago.

Comment: Welp thanks. I didn't even think to look at the reference -__-